# Decrypting a file using CipherInputStream

Tags: android, encryption

I have a requirement where i need to download a video file in encrypted form and while playing i need to decrypt and play. For this i am using CipherOutputSStream and CipherInputStream. I have using the below code for encrypting and decrypting the files. Encryption is happening smoothly, but my decryption for an 11 mb file is taking a very long time. And also the decrypted file is unable to play. Below are my codes.I have created a Custom Data source class, but i am unable to attach it to exoplayer. How can i attach my custom data source class to an exoplayer.

```
public final class EncryptedFileDataSource implements DataSource {

private final TransferListener<? super EncryptedFileDataSource> mTransferListener;
private StreamingCipherInputStream mInputStream;
private Uri mUri;
private long mBytesRemaining;
private boolean mOpened;
private Cipher mCipher;

public EncryptedFileDataSource(Cipher cipher, TransferListener<? super EncryptedFileDataSource> listener) {
    mCipher = cipher;
    mTransferListener = listener;
}

@Override
public long open(DataSpec dataSpec) throws EncryptedFileDataSourceException {
    // if we're open, we shouldn't need to open again, fast-fail
    if (mOpened) {
        return mBytesRemaining;
    }
    // #getUri is part of the contract...
    mUri = dataSpec.uri;
    // put all our throwable work in a single block, wrap the error in a custom Exception
    try {
        setupInputStream();
        skipToPosition(dataSpec);
        computeBytesRemaining(dataSpec);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new EncryptedFileDataSourceException(e);
    }
    // if we made it this far, we're open
    mOpened = true;
    // notify
    if (mTransferListener != null) {
        mTransferListener.onTransferStart(this, dataSpec);
    }
    // report
    return mBytesRemaining;
}

private void setupInputStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File encryptedFile = new File(mUri.getPath());
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
    mInputStream = new StreamingCipherInputStream(fileInputStream, mCipher);
}

private void skipToPosition(DataSpec dataSpec) throws IOException {
    mInputStream.forceSkip(dataSpec.position);
}

private void computeBytesRemaining(DataSpec dataSpec) throws IOException {
    if (dataSpec.length != C.LENGTH_UNSET) {
        mBytesRemaining = dataSpec.length;
    } else {
        mBytesRemaining = mInputStream.available();
        if (mBytesRemaining == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            mBytesRemaining = C.LENGTH_UNSET;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int readLength) throws EncryptedFileDataSourceException {
    // fast-fail if there's 0 quantity requested or we think we've already processed everything
    if (readLength == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (mBytesRemaining == 0) {
        return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT;
    }
    // constrain the read length and try to read from the cipher input stream
    int bytesToRead = getBytesToRead(readLength);
    int bytesRead;
    try {
        bytesRead = mInputStream.read(buffer, offset, bytesToRead);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new EncryptedFileDataSourceException(e);
    }
    // if we get a -1 that means we failed to read - we're either going to EOF error or broadcast EOF
    if (bytesRead == -1) {
        if (mBytesRemaining != C.LENGTH_UNSET) {
            throw new EncryptedFileDataSourceException(new EOFException());
        }
        return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT;
    }
    // we can't decrement bytes remaining if it's just a flag representation (as opposed to a mutable numeric quantity)
    if (mBytesRemaining != C.LENGTH_UNSET) {
        mBytesRemaining -= bytesRead;
    }
    // notify
    if (mTransferListener != null) {
        mTransferListener.onBytesTransferred(this, bytesRead);
    }
    // report
    return bytesRead;
}

private int getBytesToRead(int bytesToRead) {
    if (mBytesRemaining == C.LENGTH_UNSET) {
        return bytesToRead;
    }
    return (int) Math.min(mBytesRemaining, bytesToRead);
}

@Override
public Uri getUri() {
    return mUri;
}

@Override
public void close() throws EncryptedFileDataSourceException {
    mUri = null;
    try {
        if (mInputStream != null) {
            mInputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new EncryptedFileDataSourceException(e);
    } finally {
        mInputStream = null;
        if (mOpened) {
            mOpened = false;
            if (mTransferListener != null) {
                mTransferListener.onTransferEnd(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static final class EncryptedFileDataSourceException extends IOException {
    public EncryptedFileDataSourceException(IOException cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}

public static class StreamingCipherInputStream extends CipherInputStream {

    private int mBytesAvailable;

    public StreamingCipherInputStream(InputStream is, Cipher c) {
        super(is, c);
        try {
            mBytesAvailable = is.available();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // let it be 0
        }
    }

    // if the CipherInputStream has returns 0 from #skip, #read out enough bytes to get where we need to be
    public long forceSkip(long bytesToSkip) throws IOException {
        long processedBytes = 0;
        while (processedBytes < bytesToSkip) {
            long bytesSkipped = skip(bytesToSkip - processedBytes);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0) {
                if (read() == -1) {
                    throw new EOFException();
                }
                bytesSkipped = 1;
            }
            processedBytes += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return processedBytes;
    }

    // We need to return the available bytes from the upstream.
    // In this implementation we're front loading it, but it's possible the value might change during the lifetime
    // of this instance, and reference to the stream should be retained and queried for available bytes instead
    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
        return mBytesAvailable;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you want to keep the whole video data in `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: I am not sure abt it, can you suggest me any better approach to decrypt the file

Comment: use [exoplyer](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/), it will decrypt it on the fly

Comment: oh is it? Like after i encrypted the file using cipher, the if i just pass the path of that file to the exoplayer, it will automatically do the encryption and play?

Comment: But while encrypting the file, i am generating a key. From where will exoplayer get the key to decrypt the file?

Comment: you have to setup it first

Comment: any sample u have to get reference from

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer

Comment: This documentation is really not upto the mark. Anyway thanks for ur effort.

Comment: what you mean: not upto the mark? you wanted some samples, so i gave you them [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer#sample-code)

Comment: I was looking for sample code. I have already gone through the doc earlier

Comment: did you see the link i posted? it says: `Sample code`

Comment: The sample code is too big. I want specific encryption related thing which i have found can be achieved through CustomData source and linking it to player

Comment: so 5 minute googling gives: https://www.codesd.com/item/android-encrypted-audio-player.html - it mentions `AesCipherDataSource`

Comment: Edited my question, can u tell me how can i attach my custom data source to my exo player

Comment: player.prepare(encryptedFileDataSource); gives compiler error

Comment: most likely by providing a custom `DataSource.Factory` - see https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html - they say: `"By providing a custom factory it’s possible to load data from a non-standard source or through a different network stack."`

Answer (score -1):

Finally i have found solution to it. It might help some. First of all we will need to create a Custom Data source class to handle decryption of our locally stored encrypted video file. Below is that class

EncryptedFileDataSource:

```
public final class EncryptedFileDataSource implements DataSource {

private final TransferListener<? super EncryptedFileDataSource> mTransferListener;
private StreamingCipherInputStream mInputStream;
private Uri mUri;
private long mBytesRemaining;
private boolean mOpened;
private Cipher mCipher;

public EncryptedFileDataSource(Cipher cipher, TransferListener<? super EncryptedFileDataSource> listener) {
    mCipher = cipher;
    mTransferListener = listener;
}

@Override
public long open(DataSpec dataSpec) throws EncryptedFileDataSourceException {
    // if we're open, we shouldn't need to open again, fast-fail
    if (mOpened) {
        return mBytesRemaining;
    }
    // #getUri is part of the contract...
    mUri = dataSpec.uri;
    // put all our throwable work in a single block, wrap the error in a custom Exception
    try {
        setupInputStream();
        skipToPosition(dataSpec);
        computeBytesRemaining(dataSpec);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new EncryptedFileDataSourceException(e);
    }
    // if we made it this far, we're open
    mOpened = true;
    // notify
    if (mTransferListener != null) {
        mTransferListener.onTransferStart(this, dataSpec);
    }
    // report
    return mBytesRemaining;
}

private void setupInputStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File encryptedFile = new File(mUri.getPath());
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
    mInputStream = new StreamingCipherInputStream(fileInputStream, mCipher);
}

private void skipToPosition(DataSpec dataSpec) throws IOException {
    mInputStream.forceSkip(dataSpec.position);
}

private void computeBytesRemaining(DataSpec dataSpec) throws IOException {
    if (dataSpec.length != C.LENGTH_UNSET) {
        mBytesRemaining = dataSpec.length;
    } else {
        mBytesRemaining = mInputStream.available();
        if (mBytesRemaining == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            mBytesRemaining = C.LENGTH_UNSET;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int readLength) throws EncryptedFileDataSourceException {
    // fast-fail if there's 0 quantity requested or we think we've already processed everything
    if (readLength == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (mBytesRemaining == 0) {
        return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT;
    }
    // constrain the read length and try to read from the cipher input stream
    int bytesToRead = getBytesToRead(readLength);
    int bytesRead;
    try {
        bytesRead = mInputStream.read(buffer, offset, bytesToRead);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new EncryptedFileDataSourceException(e);
    }
    // if we get a -1 that means we failed to read - we're either going to EOF error or broadcast EOF
    if (bytesRead == -1) {
        if (mBytesRemaining != C.LENGTH_UNSET) {
            throw new EncryptedFileDataSourceException(new EOFException());
        }
        return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT;
    }
    // we can't decrement bytes remaining if it's just a flag representation (as opposed to a mutable numeric quantity)
    if (mBytesRemaining != C.LENGTH_UNSET) {
        mBytesRemaining -= bytesRead;
    }
    // notify
    if (mTransferListener != null) {
        mTransferListener.onBytesTransferred(this, bytesRead);
    }
    // report
    return bytesRead;
}

private int getBytesToRead(int bytesToRead) {
    if (mBytesRemaining == C.LENGTH_UNSET) {
        return bytesToRead;
    }
    return (int) Math.min(mBytesRemaining, bytesToRead);
}

@Override
public Uri getUri() {
    return mUri;
}

@Override
public void close() throws EncryptedFileDataSourceException {
    mUri = null;
    try {
        if (mInputStream != null) {
            mInputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new EncryptedFileDataSourceException(e);
    } finally {
        mInputStream = null;
        if (mOpened) {
            mOpened = false;
            if (mTransferListener != null) {
                mTransferListener.onTransferEnd(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static final class EncryptedFileDataSourceException extends IOException {
    public EncryptedFileDataSourceException(IOException cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}

public static class StreamingCipherInputStream extends CipherInputStream {

    private int mBytesAvailable;

    public StreamingCipherInputStream(InputStream is, Cipher c) {
        super(is, c);
        try {
            mBytesAvailable = is.available();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // let it be 0
        }
    }

    // if the CipherInputStream has returns 0 from #skip, #read out enough bytes to get where we need to be
    public long forceSkip(long bytesToSkip) throws IOException {
        long processedBytes = 0;
        while (processedBytes < bytesToSkip) {
            long bytesSkipped = skip(bytesToSkip - processedBytes);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0) {
                if (read() == -1) {
                    throw new EOFException();
                }
                bytesSkipped = 1;
            }
            processedBytes += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return processedBytes;
    }

    // We need to return the available bytes from the upstream.
    // In this implementation we're front loading it, but it's possible the value might change during the lifetime
    // of this instance, and reference to the stream should be retained and queried for available bytes instead
    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
        return mBytesAvailable;
    }
}
```

}

Then to initialize ExoPlayer and PlayerView classes and bind our custom data source we can use the below method

```
private void prepareExoPlayerFromFileUri(Uri uri) {

    try {
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        // 2. Create a default LoadControl
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

        // 3. Create the player
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
        player.addListener(this);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(uri);
        Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("ARC4");
        aes.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("secretkey".getBytes(), "ARC4"));
        final EncryptedFileDataSource fileDataSource = new EncryptedFileDataSource(aes, new TransferListener<EncryptedFileDataSource>() {
            @Override
            public void onTransferStart(EncryptedFileDataSource source, DataSpec dataSpec) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBytesTransferred(EncryptedFileDataSource source, int bytesTransferred) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransferEnd(EncryptedFileDataSource source) {

            }
        });
        try {
            fileDataSource.open(dataSpec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DataSource.Factory factory = new DataSource.Factory() {
            @Override
            public DataSource createDataSource() {
                return fileDataSource;
            }
        };
        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(fileDataSource.getUri(),
                factory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);

        player.prepare(videoSource);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Finally we can call that method in the below given way

```
  prepareExoPlayerFromFileUri(Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: Please add a text explanation of what the fix is.

Comment: It's still missing the *why* it is now playing smoothly (this without looking at the source files).

Comment: because now i am attaching  our custom data source to play the encrypted local files. All the required code i have provided above